# Finding out which side of a 2D AABBxAABB collided?

Tags: java, android, 2d, collision-detection

I'm making a breakout/brick-breaker/arkanoid clone (opengl-es/android) and I've been stuck on my collision detection code for quite some time. As the title suggests: How do I figure out which side of a brick has been hit by the ball ?

Since I only need to invert the speed in a certain direction, x or y, when a brick is hit I could think of:

```
 if(speedY < 0) : left, upper or right
 else : left, bottom or right
 if(speedX < 0) : bottom, right or upper
 else : bottom, left or upper
```

however this doesn't bring me far in deciding if it collided vertical or horizontal, and with that, which direction I should send the ball next.

I've looked at some code examples on the internet, however those often are very vague, complicated or off-topic for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you know the position of the Brick and the position of the ball you can do tests on each object to determine the side of the brick.

Assuming the standard Java origin in the top-left:

```
   +----+
( )|    |
   +----+
```

If the ball's Max-X is < the Min-X of the brick, you know that it has to be on the left side, and vice versa with the right and left. You would also test the `Y` values for top and bottom collisions.

Of course this assumes you've gotten the collision detection working first.

---

**EDIT**

---

This is an excerpt from my Collision engine, this is just a small bit for an example, but this is how I test if the object is to the left of the thing it's colliding with.

```
else if ((oCenter.getX() < sCenter.getX()) 
        && ((oCenter.getY() < (sCenter.getY() + sourceHalfHeight)) 
        && (oCenter.getY() > (sCenter.getY() - sourceHalfHeight))))
    return LEFT;
```

In my example here `oCenter` is a `Point2D` and it's the center of the ball. `sCenter` is a `Point2D` and it's the center of a rectangular shape. `sourceHalfHeight` is half the height of the rectangular shape (the object with the center point `sCenter`).

The Pseudo-code algorithm:

```
if (the center X of the ball < the center X of the rectangle
        AND the center Y of the ball is BETWEEN the max Y and min Y of the rectangle)
    then the ball is to the LEFT of the rectangle
end if
```

Comment: with your method, testing if ball.maxX < brick.minX there wouldn't be any collision at all. Or am I understanding it wrong ?

Comment: @user717572 Yes, you are correct, however I was just giving a simple example on how to determine which side of the object the ball collided with. The comparisons are a bit more complex but the idea came across.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, you cannot know it with the speed only, as the ball could hit 2 different sides at 2 different times, both times with the same speed in the same direction.

Ex:
First line hits the top, second one hits the side, but both have the same speed and direction

```
      /
     /   /
 _____  /
|_____|
```

You would have to use the ball's position and compare it with each sides of the brick